# SQL statement to increment multiple case functions from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm trying to increment the SQL generated column "Counter" by making 1 case statement.
I get the error "Invalid Column" for Counter in my case statement. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT 0 as Counter(Not part of any table),
CASE
          WHEN dateadd(HOUR, -1,GETDATE()) >= max (a.UPDATED_DATE)
          THEN
             Counter + 1 
WHEN dateadd(HOUR, -1,GETDATE()) >= max (b.UPDATED_DATE)
          THEN
             Counter + 1          
          ELSE
             Counter + 0
       END  as Counter
FROM dbo.My_Dates a, Client_Dates b
```

Comment: You can't reference a column by its alias within the same scope. Also, it's a `CASE` **expression**. Though the description here makes little sense if I am honest.

Comment: Don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: ...or [meaningless aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shot in the dark. It's not clear what order you need the rows to be counted or what the relationship between the two tables is.

```
with m as (
    SELECT *,
        case when max(a.UPDATED_DATE) over () >    max(b.UPDATED_DATE) over ()
             then max(a.UPDATED_DATE) over () else max(b.UPDATED_DATE) over () end as last_update
    FROM dbo.My_Dates a, Client_Dates b /* this cross join surely isn't right */
)
select
    count(case when dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) >= last_update then 1 end)
        over (order by ??)
from m;
```

Per comment below it appears you just need to count the maxima across a bunch of tables:

```
with d(last_updated) as (
    select max(UPDATED_DATE) from T1  union all
    select max(UPDATED_DATE) from T2  union all ...
    select max(UPDATED_DATE) from T16
)
select count(case when dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) >= last_update then 1 end) from d;
```

Comment: Hey @shawnt00, essentially I need to get a count  of how many tables out of  16 tables where the updated_date hasn't been updated in the last 4 hours. So I was thinking if I just did a case on all 16 to increment the counter that it would work. So I didn't think I'd need to perform any joins.

Comment: @Christopher No, you definitely don't want to try a cross join with sixteen tables. The joins are still there in the form of a cartesian product that would basically crash your server.